# Load Digital Map on Android

Tags: android

I have to do an application on the Android platform which should load a digital map  on the phone. The digital map is a .vsd file and it represents the map of a building. What  I need for the moment is when I touch the phone screen inside a room I want to modify the border color of this room (I want to select it in a visual way).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no Java library to read/parse/display a MS Visio file (.vsd).

So there is no way to do this, except if you decide to write your own parser and renderer for .vsd files.